# XML Serialization C#: There is an error in XML document (6, 4)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I try to send a XML file to a service. I use following method to send it;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Sample
{
    public class SampleHttpResquestAndResponse
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adonis servisi ile iletişim kurmayı sağlar.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">T</typeparam>
        /// <param name="prm_ServiceName">string</param> SearchHotels //  BasketHotels //  ConfirmHotels
        /// <param name="prm_Criteria">object</param>
        /// <param name="prm_Url">string</param> "http://xmltest.adonis.com/AdonisServices"
        /// <returns>T</returns>
        public static T AdonisRequestResponseMethod<T>(string prm_ServiceName, object prm_Criteria, string prm_Url)
        {
            #region Variables
            HttpWebRequest HttpWebRequest;
            T ReturnValue;
            #endregion

            try
            {
                #region Xml Serializer
                var XmlString = SampleHttpResquestAndResponse.ConvertTypeToXml<object>(prm_Criteria).ToString();
                #endregion

                #region Http Web Request
                HttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}?prm_CurrentData={2}", prm_Url, prm_ServiceName, XmlString));
                HttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
                HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                HttpWebRequest.Timeout = 80000000;
                #endregion

                #region Http Web Response
                StreamWriter StreamWriterPost = new StreamWriter(HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
                StreamWriterPost.Write(XmlString);

                StreamWriterPost.Close();
                HttpWebResponse HttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader StreamReaderResponse = new StreamReader(HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                string StringResponse = string.Empty;

                if (HttpWebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                {
                    using (GZipStream decompress = new GZipStream(HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(decompress);
                        StringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                    StringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                #endregion

                #region Return Value Type Process (DESERIALIZE)
                ReturnValue = SampleHttpResquestAndResponse.ConvertXmlToType<T>(StringResponse.ToString()).Data;
                #endregion

                #region Return Value
                return ReturnValue;
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                #region Return Value
                return ReturnValue = SampleHttpResquestAndResponse.ConvertXmlToType<T>(ex.Message).Data;
                #endregion
            }
        }

        public static ResultDTO<T> ConvertXmlToType<T>(string prm_Xml)
        {
            #region Variables
            T ReturnValue;
            #endregion

            try
            {
                #region Replace String Value
                prm_Xml = prm_Xml.Replace("xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\""
                                        , "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"");
                prm_Xml = prm_Xml.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&quot;", "\"");
                #endregion

                #region Deserialize
                using (MemoryStream MemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(MemoryStream))
                    {
                        StreamWriter.Write(prm_Xml);
                        StreamWriter.Flush();
                        MemoryStream.Position = 0;
                        XmlSerializer XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                        using (StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader(MemoryStream))
                        {
                            StreamReader.ReadLine();
                            #region Result Value (SET)
                            ReturnValue = (T)XmlSerializer.Deserialize(StreamReader);
                            #endregion
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                #region Return Value
                return new ResultDTO<T>
                {
                    Data = ReturnValue,
                    Success = true
                };
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                #region Return Value
                return new ResultDTO<T>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = string.Format("Error Type : {0} Code : {1} Method Name : {2} Error Mesage : {3}", "Undetermined", "1000", "ConvertXmlToType", ex.Message),
                };
                #endregion
            }
        }

        public static string ConvertTypeToXml<T>(T prm_Criteria)
        {
            #region Variables
            XmlSerializer XmlSerializer;
            StringWriter StringWriter = new StringWriter();
            #endregion

            try
            {
                #region Xml Serializer
                XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(prm_Criteria.GetType());
                XmlSerializer.Serialize(StringWriter, prm_Criteria);
                var XmlString = StringWriter.ToString();
                #endregion

                #region Request Replace
                return XmlString = XmlString.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>", "");
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.SuppressFinalize(StringWriter);
            }

        }
    }

    public class ResultDTO
    {
        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// İslem durumu.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// İşlem mesajı.
        /// </summary>
        public string Message { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

    public class ResultDTO<T> : ResultDTO
    {
        #region Fields
        /// <summary>
        /// Generic data tipi.
        /// </summary>
        private T data = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Generic data tipi
        /// </summary>
        public T Data
        {
            get
            {
                if (data == null)
                    return data = default(T);
                return data;
            }
            set { data = value; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Before that, I create an object which is used as `prm_Criteria` when I call `AdonisRequestResponseMethod`. This is how i create it;

```
public string searchByCity(string cityID)
        {

            AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO searchObj = new AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO();
            searchObj.CheckInDate = "20151020";
            searchObj.CheckOutDate = "20151021";
            searchObj.CityID = cityID;
            searchObj.CountryID = "161";
            searchObj.NationalityCode = "TR";

            searchObj.PaginationData = new PaginationData();
            searchObj.PaginationData.ItemsPerPage = "2000";
            searchObj.PaginationData.PageNumber = "1";
            RoomCriteria rcriteria = new RoomCriteria();
            rcriteria.RoomCriteriaDTO = new RoomCriteriaDTO();
            rcriteria.RoomCriteriaDTO.AdultCount = "2";
            rcriteria.RoomCriteriaDTO.ChildCount = "0";
            rcriteria.RoomCriteriaDTO.RoomCount = "1";

            searchObj.RoomCriteria = rcriteria;
            searchObj.Credentials = login();

            string param1 = "SearchHotels";
            object param2 = searchObj;
            string param3 = "http://xmltest.adonis.com/AdonisServices";

            string res = SampleHttpResquestAndResponse.AdonisRequestResponseMethod<string>(param1, param2, param3);

            return res;


        }
```

And this is my `AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO` object;

```
 public class AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO
    {
        public string CheckInDate { get; set; }
        public string CheckOutDate { get; set; }
        public string CityID { get; set; }
        public string CountryID { get; set; }
        public string HotelID { get; set; }
        public string NationalityCode { get; set; }
        public PaginationData PaginationData { get; set; }
        public RoomCriteria RoomCriteria { get; set; }
        public Credentials Credentials { get; set; }


    }
```

The XML is created in this method is like this;

```
<AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CheckInDate>20151020</CheckInDate> 
  <CheckOutDate>20151021</CheckOutDate> 
  <CityID>28674</CityID> 
  <CountryID>161</CountryID> 
  <NationalityCode>TR</NationalityCode> 
- <PaginationData>
  <PageNumber>1</PageNumber> 
  <ItemsPerPage>2000</ItemsPerPage> 
  </PaginationData>
- <RoomCriteria>
- <RoomCriteriaDTO>
  <AdultCount>2</AdultCount> 
  <RoomCount>1</RoomCount> 
  <ChildCount>0</ChildCount> 
  </RoomCriteriaDTO>
  </RoomCriteria>
- <Credentials>
  <clientID>----</clientID> 
  <username>---</username> 
  <password>----</password> 
  </Credentials>
  </AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO>
```

It is the data in XmlString variable in AdonisRequestResponseMethod. During the execution StringResponse variable gets this value, which is not expected;

```
<AdonisHotelSearchResultDTO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Errors>
    <ErrorMessage>Error Type : Undetermined Code : 1000 Method Name : ConvertXmlToType Error Mesage : There is an error in XML document (6, 4).</ErrorMessage>
  </Errors>
  <AvailableHotel />
</AdonisHotelSearchResultDTO>
```

At the end of debugging I face with some exceptions like; InvalidOperationException and MissingMethodException.

What I want is not like that. I expect AdonisHotelSearchResultDTO should be filled results of search method obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a lot of very strange things in `ConvertXmlToType` with `MemoryStream`, `StreamWriter`, `StreamReader`.

I haven't taken the time to fully understand it, but something here is meaning the serializer probably isn't reading what you think it is.  My guess is the call to `StreamReader.ReadLine()` means the serializer starts in the wrong place.

Why not use something far more straightforward?  With your XML, this works for me:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));

using (var reader = new StringReader(prm_Xml))
{
    ReturnValue = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: I know it is a little bit (maybe more than a little bit) complicated. Anyway, I will try your suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your serialized class should look like this

```css
    [XmlRoot("AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO")]
    public class AdonisHotelSearchCriteriaDTO
    {
        public string CheckInDate { get; set; }
        public string CheckOutDate { get; set; }
        public string CityID { get; set; }
        public string CountryID { get; set; }
        public string HotelID { get; set; }
        public string NationalityCode { get; set; }
        public PaginationData PaginationData { get; set; }
        public RoomCriteria RoomCriteria { get; set; }
        public Credentials Credentials { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("PaginationData")]
    public class PaginationData
    {
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("RoomCriteria")]
    public class RoomCriteria
    {
        RoomCriteriaDTO RoomCriteriaDTO { get; set; } 
    }
    [XmlRoot("RoomCriteriaDTO")]
    public class RoomCriteriaDTO
    {
        public int AdultCount { get; set; }
        public int RoomCount { get; set; }
        public int ChildCount { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Credentials")]
    public class Credentials
    {
        public int clientID { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```